# read_json returns empty dataframe using pandas.read_json

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm running this code but the api stopped to send bets values, how can i dataframe the "vazio" to scrappe values inside?

```
vazio='https://api-v2.blaze.com/roulette_games/current'
    
urlData = requests.get(vazio).content
rodadaatual = pd.read_json(io.StringIO(urlData.decode('utf-8')))
```

output

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, color, roll, created_at, updated_at, status, total_red_eur_bet, total_red_bets_placed, total_white_eur_bet, total_white_bets_placed, total_black_eur_bet, total_black_bets_placed, bets]
Index: []
```

Comment: how are we supposed to guess what a `request` to a random API will output?

Comment: I think he wants an empty dataframe with a column index of the keys of the json response. Vazio mean empty in portuguese so i am guessing here

Comment: yes, i want the data on this link, but he returning a empty Dataframe

Comment: Hi @LucasMendes can you try my answer and let me know if it helps. If it does please consider accepting the answer by clicking on check symbol left of the answer box

Comment: Hey @LucasMendes, can you atleast confirm if answer worked for you or not

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the data you read in a valid json list format. Then you can use [`pandas.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) to read the json data

```
urlData = '[' + urlData.decode('utf-8') + ']'
pd.read_json(urlData)
```

##### Output :

This gives us the desired dataframe

```
           id  color  roll  ... total_black_eur_bet total_black_bets_placed bets
0  BylLAX00rG    NaN   NaN  ...                   0                       0   []

[1 rows x 13 columns]
```